# Understanding ng-show in AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-show

Given the following code:

http://jsbin.com/uYETOSUM/2/edit?html,js,output

I want to only show the first dropdown first (parent question in JSON). After user have selected an option I want to show one of the two other dropdowns (children in additionalQuestion object in JSON). Which dropdown to show is given in the JSON used to create the form input fields.

To do this I've experimented with `ng-show`, but I don't seem to find the proper place to put the custom `ng-show` code. I want `ng-show` to be like this in the template:

```
ng-show"showQuestion()"
```

where `showQuestion()` iterates through all questions and matches the `PreviousQuestionConstraint` to see which of the other questions to show based on the value of the selected option in the first question.

- Should it be in the Controller?
- Should it be in the Directive?
- Should it be in the linker function in the Directive?

All attempts so far have resulted in nothing being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hassle I've managed to get a working example for you using the `&attr` isolated scope syntax which provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope, in your example all the way up to the `showQuestion()` function on your QuestionsCtrl controller.

http://jsbin.com/EkIqAju/2/edit

Comment: That's great! If it was a lot of hassle, maybe it's not the correct approach for Angular? Ie. how do I get the object for the current directive in the `showQuestion()` function? In other words, how do I access the question object that is being validated against `showQuestion()` in the Controller?

Comment: @user3097455 I've never really worked with recursive directives like your example before, found that I had to use two separate attribute names for each of the two directives to work. Given your requirement I think that is the right approach.